# Send url when its done

Tags: php, url, post, get

I want to send call a url after building it. this is the code so far.

```
   $producten = '';
   foreach ($orders as $product) {
       $producten .= "&articlecode=" . $product['productTitle'] . "&color=NAVY&size=" . $product['variantTitle'] . "&qty=" . $product['quantityOrdered'] . "&price=" . number_format($product['priceIncl'], 2) * 100;
}

    $url= file_get_contents('http://api.softwear.nl/scripts/foxisapi.dll/sww1.wreq1.mpx?sendorder&token=' . $swToken . '
                        &custnum=' . $custNum . '&email=' . $email . '&title=' . $gender . '&firstname=' . $firstname . '&middlename=' . $middlename . '&lastname=' . $lastname . '
                        &street=' . $addressBillingName . '&housenum=' . $addressBillingNumber . '&zipcode=' . $addressBillingZipcode . '&city=' . $addressBillingCity . '
                        &countrycode=' . $code . '&shipping=' . $shipmentTrim . '&discount=' . $discountTrim . '&refid=' . $referralId . $producten++); 

echo $url;
```

If i do it with header(location) it's fine but its not the way to work this out i think.

Comment: use curl as an alternative

Comment: I think `$producten++` is not correct here

Answer (score 0):

I got it. Here is the code for people with the same question.

```
    /* cURL Resource */
$ch = curl_init();

/* Set URL */
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://api.softwear.nl/scripts/foxisapi.dll/sww1.wreq1.mpx?sendorder&token=' . $swToken . '
                        &custnum=' . $custNum . '&email=' . $email . '&title=' . $gender . '&firstname=' . $firstname . '&middlename=' . $middlename . '&lastname=' . $lastname . '
                        &street=' . $addressBillingName . '&housenum=' . $addressBillingNumber . '&zipcode=' . $addressBillingZipcode . '&city=' . $addressBillingCity . '
                        &countrycode=' . $code . '&shipping=' . $shipmentTrim . '&discount=' . $discountTrim . '&refid=' . $referralId . $producten++);

/* Tell cURL to return the output */
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

/* Tell cURL NOT to return the headers */
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);

/* Execute cURL, Return Data */
$data = curl_exec($ch);

/* Check HTTP Code */
$status = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);

/* Close cURL Resource */
curl_close($ch);

/* 200 Response! */
if ($status == 200) {

    /* Debug */
    var_dump($data);

} else {

    /* Debug */
    var_dump($data);
    var_dump($status);

}
```